# Ошибка sscanf Segmentation fault

Tags: c

Sscanf выдает ошибку, возьмем этот код:

```
char * args = malloc(100);
strcpy(args, "Simple_str 123");
char * str;
int num = 0;
sscanf(args, "%s %d", str, &num);
printf("%s %d", str, num);
```

Вывод: `Simple_str 123`

Вроде так и должно быть, окей, возьмем этот код:

```
char * args = malloc(100);
strcpy(args, "Simple_str 123");
char * str;
int num = 0;
sscanf(args, "%s %d", str, &num); // <--- ошибка здесь
printf("%s %d", str, num);

memset(args, 0, 100);
strcpy(args, "Simple_str");
sscanf(args, "%s", str);          // <--- иногда здесь
printf("%s; %s\n", args, str);
```

Как это работает?

Компилирую: `gcc -std=c99 main.c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта грубо ошибочны. `str` - указатель, указывающий "в никуда". А вы через него пытаетесь что-то записывать. Вот и получается "Segmentation fault".

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы просто спасли мой день! Заменил, заработало: 
`char * str;` ---> `char * str = malloc(100);`

Comment: @Я в отчаяние: ...и не "Я в отчаяние", а "Я в отчаянии".

Comment: упс `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @AnT А может, он не где, а куда направляется?...